# How to create a custom Drawer Menu with 3 views in last row

Tags: android, drawer

I have to create a DrawerMenu. But i sucked because in last row there are 3 different. How to create and handle 3 different view in last item.

[image: Drawer Menu]

Comment: add a custom layout  in your xml code and make it visible in your last position and hide in other positions. This is the logic what we can do.

Comment: Just change in your Drawer XML layout file. In that file add 3 another views. 1. for user info, 2nd for Menu and 3rd for the last three menu its easy.

Comment: Where you got the problem?

Comment: can i see your code? So it's easy to understand us.